# A pendulum stuck on a horisontal slider and jamming

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I'm wondering if my idea of conservation of energy is correct when it comes to a pendulum attached to a slider, and what happens during a jam.

I have worked out the equations of motion, and assuming $x$ defines the position of the connected point that slides, I am wondering what happens to the pendulum if the slide jams.

I believe I can look at conservation of energy and that the energy from the slide can be translated into the pendulums rotational kinetic energy.

Am I correct to assume this? Also, how would this look in the equations of motion?

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic energy is often lost in collisions.  If a system is moving along and jams, you can't assume the total energy is the same before and after the collision.

The jammed part is able to exert a force on the pendulum, but no torque.  If you could calculate the angular momentum of the pendulum immediately before the collision, it should be the same immediately after.  That, plus the position of the pendulum will give you the energy remaining in just the pendulum part.